# How to test published Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When I develop a Chrome Extension locally, its icon is in the browser action bar. When I install a published version of my extension, there are now two of the same icons in the browser action bar. Sometimes I can't remember which is which.

If I open an incognito browser tab, I can't seem to load any extensions. But what I want to do is test my published extension in a sandbox, where I know I have the latest version.

**What is the best way to test a published extension on the same machine where you develop the extension?**

Comment: One way seems to be - allow only the published extension in incognito mode - then after publishing, open a new tab in incognito mode and you know that extension is the published one...?

Comment: the problem with using incognito mode, is that if I open the extension in incognito mode, it opens the extension page in the regular browser window, not in the incognito window

Comment: Why not delete the local chrome extension so you don't get confused?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to [create a new profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) in Chrome to test your local extension.

You can also drag and drop the browser action items, so you could move the development extension all the way to the left and the published one all the way to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have installed 4 versions of a Chrome extension I'm developing:

- One loaded from the unpacked source files, for debugging
- One loaded from the minified code in a build directory, for testing how speedy it feels in day-to-day use
- The published version installed from the webstore
- A completely separate test version installed from the webstore

As Matt suggests, I've rearranged the icons on the Chrome toolbar, putting the minified version on the left, then the source version, then the ones from the webstore.

But this can still be a bit confusing, so I've also changed the build process a bit.  The `manifest.json` now sets both the `name` and `browser_action.default_title` fields to `"My Extension DEV"`.  This string is shown in the tooltip of the version I've loaded from the source directory.

During the minification process, I have the build script change these values to `"My Extension OUT (build time)"`, so I can see when the minified version was last built in the tooltip.

The script that actually packages the minified files into a `.zip` file for upload to the webstore then resets these values to what the published extension should show.

You could also change these strings at runtime instead of as part of the build process.  If you have a background page, it could call `chrome.management.getSelf()` and then check the response's `installType` key.  If it's `"development"`, then you could call `chrome.browserAction.setTitle("DEV")` to indicate in the tooltip that it's the unpacked version of the extension.